# Interpreter issues in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thought I would ask here of all places. I have a script written that will not run.

```
    def quiz_decimal(low, high):
        float(low)
        float(high)
        num = float(input('Type a number between', low, 'and', high, end=':\n')
        if num < low:
            print('No,', num ,'is less than', low)
        elif num > high:
            print('No,', num, 'is greather than', high)
        elif num > low and num < high
            print('Good!', low, '<', num, '<', high )
```

The 3.6.2 IDLE environment says that there is an issue with the colon in line 5, but this seems in the right place for an if statement. What's the matter?

Comment: missing parenthesis in the line before...

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of line 4, and a `:` on line 9. That should do the trick!

Comment: Wow, rookie mistake... thanks for spotting!

Comment: If you're getting an error on a particular line (especially a syntax error), you should always pay close attention to the previous line(s) as well. Something I've learnt from debugging many similar errors. ;)

Comment: Also, calling `float(low)` and `float(high)` at the beginning of the function is pointless if you don't assign the result to a variable, e.g. `low = float(low)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parenthesis on line 4. num = float(input...))

```
def quiz_decimal(low, high):
        float(low)
        float(high)
        num = float(input('Type a number between', low, 'and', high, end=':\n'))
        if num < low:
            print('No,', num ,'is less than', low)
        elif num > high:
            print('No,', num, 'is greather than', high)
        elif num > low and num < high
            print('Good!', low, '<', num, '<', high )
```